# Consecutively numbered tickets in consecutive blocks

Tags: combinatorics

The number of ways in which 3 children can distribute 10 tickets out of 15 consecutively numbered tickets among themselves such that they get consecutive blocks of 5,3 and 2 tickets is

We must prove the answer to be (8C5)3!

I know little about no.of ways of distributing identical objects by partitions, is it related to the question?
If not how to solve?

Answer (score 3):

Arrange the children in some order, say alphabetically.  The first child will receive the leftmost block of tickets, the second child will receive the middle block of tickets, and the third child will receive the rightmost block of tickets.

For now, treat the tickets as unlabeled pieces of paper.  We have eight objects to arrange in a row: a box containing five tickets, a box containing three tickets, a box containing two tickets, and five individual tickets.  Choose five of the eight positions for the individual tickets, then arrange the three distinct boxes in the remaining three positions.  Now label the tickets from left to right.  Finally, give the children the corresponding blocks of tickets.

Comment: I've Doubt that if I consider a block of $5$, a block of $3$ and a block of $2$ and $5$ different tickets. And now if i arrange them i will be getting $8!$. What is being overcounted in my case or what mistake i am making.

Comment: @user710599  The order of the five tickets that are not selected by the children does not matter.  We can select five of the eight positions for those tickets in $\binom{8}{5}$ ways, then distribute the three different sized blocks of consecutive tickets among the children in $3!$ ways.

Comment: or can i consider those $3$ block identical and $5$ remaining item identical then arrange them in $8$ position by $\frac{8!}{3!\cdot5!}$

Comment: @user710599 The three blocks are not identical since they are of different lengths.  You can choose three of the eight positions for the blocks, then arrange the three blocks within the selected positions in $\binom{8}{3}3!$ ways.